Visual Studio not recognizing unity things, and not showing unity C# autocomplete
I installed unity and Visual Studio on my computer to start working on games again, however when editing code it does not autocomplete properly and it does not recognize Unity exclusive stuff.
Screenshots:



I have tried:

Setting Visual Studio as the editor in the external tools section
Downloaded both the Unity Dev kit and the .NET kit for Visual Studio
Made it generate .csproj files for everything, and regenerated project files
Reimported all assets
Deleted .sln (no errors popped up)


Autosuggestion is based on the namespaces your file references. InputAction is part of Unity.InputSystem namespace
Add to the namespaces declaration
using Unity.InputSystem;

Also if you type class name completely, quick actions in VS might suggest you add declaration automatically

Hi, thanks for the pointer!
I guess I was used to it automatically doing it on my laptop, sorry about the stupid question though.
